# Is Java's RNG (using seeds) platform-independent?

Tags: java, cross-platform, random

Apologies in advance for asking a (seemingly obvious) question.  I haven't found an answer online, so I figured I'd ask:

**Is Java's Util.Random platform-independent?**

For Example, is `new Random(50)` going to produce the exact same sequence of random numbers in both *nix and Windows systems?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

> If two instances of `Random` are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers. In order to guarantee this property, particular algorithms are specified for the class `Random`. Java implementations must use all the algorithms shown here for the class `Random`, for the sake of absolute portability of Java code.