# Source of randomness in kotlin-stdlib-common

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

In kotlin-stdlib-common is there any source of randomness available out of the box? Whether it's some implementation of standard `java.util.Random`, `kotlin.math.random*` or basic current time millis that I can use to create my own random number generator? I can't find any.

If it's not there, how would you get the source of randomness without setting your own platform dependent implementations? This is the only method I need:

```
expect class Rng {
    fun nextInt(): Int
}
```

I'm trying to make it platform agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be: wait for Kotlin 1.3 to get released where the common library will be enriched with classes and methods that can provide the source for random values.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#multiplatform-random

Answer (score -1):

This maybe a post with many links, which may cause the problem of [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), so I try my best to write the link description. And my understanding of *Kotlin Multiplatform* is [Kotlin-Multiplatform = Kotlin-JVM + Kotlin-JS](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html).

I believe that the random number of Kotlin-JVM is provided by `java.util.Random`, and `Math.Random()` if it is Kotlin-JS, with these following reasons:

- [How can I get a random number in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685026/how-can-i-get-a-random-number-in-kotlin), and [there is an answer in that question said that Kotlin-JS can use `Math.Random()` to get random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685026/how-can-i-get-a-random-number-in-kotlin/49507413#49507413).
- [Can't get any result of any random number related method of Kotlin-JVM](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/search?p=10&q=random&unscoped_q=random), but [there is a `random()` in Kotlin-JS](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-math/random.html).
- The source code of Kotlin-JVM related file, while using `Random()`, there is a `import java.util.*`, or some file directly use `java.util.Random` for example [kotlin/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/MutableCollectionsJVM.kt#L78](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/MutableCollectionsJVM.kt#L78).

And, `java.util.Random` is designed as result platform-independent, and also implementation platform-independent, with these reason:

- [Is Java's RNG (using seeds) platform-independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060625/is-javas-rng-using-seeds-platform-independent), though this question may be out-dated.
- We can't find keyword "native" in [the source of JDK8/java.util.Random](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Random.java) or [the source of JDK10/java.util.Random](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/ffa11326afd5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java), and the RNG logic is clear in these source code, where [seed is decided by nanoTime() if not provided](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/ffa11326afd5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#l104), and [RNG is the implementation of Volume 2, TAOCP](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/ffa11326afd5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#l198).

So, I think,

> How would you get the source of randomness without setting your own platform dependent implementations?

Maybe a random-enough seed and a random-enough (P)RNG.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I can't find anything related to a question I've been asking.